# How to make a proper model in Tensorflow.js?

Tags: tensorflow, regression, tensorflow.js, non-linear-regression

i've build tensorflow.js model with polynomial regression.

```
// y = ax^3+bx^2 + cx + d
   const ys = xs.pow(tf.scalar(3)).mul(a)
        .add(xs.square().mul(b))
        .add(xs.mul(c))
        .add(d);
```

[image]

it's run very well, but when i try to change those model to this model:

```
// y = a + b*(xs/305) + c*(xs/305)^2 + d*ln(305/xs) + e*(ln(305/xs)^2)
const ys = a
    .add((xs.div(tf.scalar(305))).mul(b))
    .add((xs.div(tf.scalar(305))).square().mul(c))
    .add(((tf.scalar(305).div(xs)).log()).mul(d))
    .add(((tf.scalar(305).div(xs)).log().square()).mul(e));
```

this is the model that i want to create:

[image]

[image]

it didn't show any line, or an error. is there anything wrong with my code model?.

here's my full code :
https://github.com/fahmiSD/tensortestday

Comment: Your x bounds are from `-1` to `1`, but `ln(x)` is undefined (in the reals) for `x < 0`, so the function isn't really well-formed at that point. Additionally, if your (a,b,c,d,e) variables right now are bound from -1 to 1, then your function has a lower y-bound (in the worst case) of 2.67377 (at x=215ish), and may be off the edge of your graph.

Comment: what should i do sir? am i have to change the x bounds?

Comment: There are 2 distinct problems I pointed out. One can be solved by changing the x bounds being calculated, another can be solved by changing the viewport of the graph (i.e. what bounds it displays). Otherwise, provided that this silently fails on a bad formula, the only solution I see is to change your formula.